# Why cannot I use customized font in some sites like google search page

Tags: fonts, html, css

I modified my fonts in chrome://settings/fonts. It takes effects in some sites. But more sites are not influenced. What's behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, we can define font families. Say I wanted to use a generic sans-serif font on my `<p>` elements. Then I would do this:

```
p{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Now, this will ask the browser to use the default sans-serif font. And when you went to chrome://settings/fonts to change your fonts, it will change this default font.

However, Google likes their own fonts. So, instead they will create a custom font in css and link it to said custom font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: GooglesNiceFont;
    src: url(pure_aesthetic_genius.ttf);
}

p{
    font-family: GooglesNiceFont;
}
```

And this will always use Google's font stored on their servers, instead of the default sans serif font.